# How i can get the current page of a p-table when the page changes? and without lazy load?

Tags: angular, pagination, angular6, primeng

I have a "**p-table**" element (of **PrimeNG**) in an **Angular 6** project. I need get the rows of the current page and i don't see that control have access to pagination. Someone knows how get this data?

I tried with lazy load even, but only loads the first page.

Best regards.

Comment: What do you currently have? If you use lazy loading the `event` variable has an `event.rows` and an `event.first` Based on that you can do: `page = event.first / event.rows + 1;` to get the current page

Comment: great! but when i put the "lazy load" only loads 1 page. I have to do something more?

Comment: Yess, you have to add the `[totalRecords]` property to the table. which should hold the count of all available items. not just the items on the current page